# get repeated values in JSON object with javascript (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON object:

```
[
    {
        "idMaterial": "Alloy 450 (15Cr6Ni1.5Cu)_S45000",
        "tipoMaterial": "Alloy 450 (15Cr6Ni1.5Cu)",
        "uns": "S45000",
        "temperatura": "NL",
        "ph": "≥3,5",
        "concetracionClMax": "NL",
        "azufreElemental": "ND",
        "tratamientoTermico": "Recocido + endurecimiento por envejecido a 620ºC",
        "dureza": "31",
        "comentarios": "Cualquier combinación ",
        "origen": "NORMATIVA",
        "idEnsayo": "",
        "susceptibilidadSsc": null,
        "tipoResultado": "A",
        "ensayos": null,
        "h2S": "0,103"
    },
    {
        "idMaterial": "AISI 415 (12Cr5NiMo)_S41500",
        "tipoMaterial": "AISI 415 (12Cr5NiMo)",
        "uns": "S41500",
        "temperatura": "NL",
        "ph": "≥3,5",
        "concetracionClMax": "NL",
        "azufreElemental": "ND",
        "tratamientoTermico": "Austenitizado + templado + doble revenido",
        "dureza": "23",
        "comentarios": "Cualquier combinación de T y [Cl] en medios de producción es aceptable",
        "origen": "NORMATIVA",
        "idEnsayo": "",
        "susceptibilidadSsc": null,
        "tipoResultado": "A",
        "ensayos": null,
        "h2S": "0,103"
    },
    {
        "idMaterial": "13Cr4NiMo_S42400",
        "tipoMaterial": "13Cr4NiMo",
        "uns": "S42400",
        "temperatura": "NL",
        "ph": "≥3,5",
        "concetracionClMax": "NL",
        "azufreElemental": "No",
        "tratamientoTermico": "Austenitizado + templado + doble revenido",
        "dureza": "23",
        "comentarios": "Cualquier combinación de T y [Cl] en medios de producción es aceptable",
        "origen": "NORMATIVA",
        "idEnsayo": "",
        "susceptibilidadSsc": null,
        "tipoResultado": "A",
        "ensayos": null,
        "h2S": "0,103"
    },
    {
        "idMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)_S41425",
        "tipoMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)",
        "uns": "S41425",
        "temperatura": "NL",
        "ph": "≥3,5",
        "concetracionClMax": "NL",
        "azufreElemental": "No",
        "tratamientoTermico": "Austenitizado + templado + revenido",
        "dureza": "28",
        "comentarios": "Cualquier combinación de T y [Cl] en medios de producción es aceptable",
        "origen": "NORMATIVA",
        "idEnsayo": "",
        "susceptibilidadSsc": null,
        "tipoResultado": "A",
        "ensayos": null,
        "h2S": "0,103"
    },
    {
        "idMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)_S41426",
        "tipoMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)",
        "uns": "S41426",
        "temperatura": "NL",
        "ph": "≥3,5",
        "concetracionClMax": "NL",
        "azufreElemental": "No",
        "tratamientoTermico": "Austenitizado + templado + revenido",
        "dureza": "27",
        "comentarios": "Grado máximo 105 Ksi. Cualquier combinación de T y [Cl] en medios de producción es aceptable",
        "origen": "NORMATIVA",
        "idEnsayo": "",
        "susceptibilidadSsc": null,
        "tipoResultado": "A",
        "ensayos": null,
        "h2S": "0,103"
    },
    {
        "idMaterial": "13Cr4Ni_S41429",
        "tipoMaterial": "13Cr4Ni",
        "uns": "S41429",
        "temperatura": "NL",
        "ph": "≥4,5",
        "concetracionClMax": "NL",
        "azufreElemental": "ND",
        "tratamientoTermico": "templado + revenido o normalizado +revenido",
        "dureza": "27",
        "comentarios": "Grado máximo 120 Ksi .Cualquier combinación de T y [Cl] en medios de producción es aceptable",
        "origen": "NORMATIVA",
        "idEnsayo": "",
        "susceptibilidadSsc": null,
        "tipoResultado": "A",
        "ensayos": null,
        "h2S": "0,103"
    }
]
```

and that I want is to get all the repeated objects with the same "idMaterial" and "uns" value and put them in other object. Thanks for all (I havn't write all JSON data because is too long).

Comment: Could you post what have you tried so far?

Comment: The answer of this question in this link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76231/obtener-los-objetos-que-se-repiten-en-un-array-de-objetos-json-con-javascript-j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = [{"id":"aaa","uns":"123"},{"id":"bbb","uns":"023"},{"id":"aaa","uns":"123"},{"id":"ccc","uns":"765"},{"id":"ddd","uns":"256"}];

var isEqualFunction = function(a, b){
  return a.id === b.id && a.uns === b.uns;
}

var compareFunction = function(a, b){
  return a.id === b.id
    ? (a.uns === b.uns ? 0 : (a.uns < b.uns ? -1 : 1))
    : (a.id < b.id ? -1 : 1);
}

var arrayOrdenado = data.sort(compareFunction);
var repetidos = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOrdenado.length - 1; i++) { 
  if (isEqualFunction(arrayOrdenado[i + 1], arrayOrdenado[i])) 
  {
    repetidos.push(arrayOrdenado[i]); 
  } 
} 
console.log(repetidos);
```

Another way to do it:

```js
var data = [{"id":"aaa","uns":"123"},{"id":"bbb","uns":"023"},{"id":"aaa","uns":"123"},{"id":"ccc","uns":"765"},{"id":"ddd","uns":"256"}];

var compareFunction = function(a, b){
  return a.id === b.id
    ? (a.uns === b.uns ? 0 : (a.uns < b.uns ? -1 : 1))
    : (a.id < b.id ? -1 : 1);
}

var arrayOrdenado = data.sort(compareFunction);
var repetidos = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOrdenado.length - 1; i++) { 
  if (compareFunction(arrayOrdenado[i + 1], arrayOrdenado[i]) === 0) 
  {
    repetidos.push(arrayOrdenado[i]); 
  } 
} 
console.log(repetidos);
```

This question was asked and resolved in SO spanish, and this is the link of it https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76231/obtener-los-objetos-que-se-repiten-en-un-array-de-objetos-json-con-javascript-j

Answer (score 2):

Assign your object to a variable,

```
var obj = [
    {
        "idMaterial": "Alloy 450 (15Cr6Ni1.5Cu)_S45000",
        "tipoMaterial": "Alloy 450 (15Cr6Ni1.5Cu)",
        "uns": "S45000",
        "temperatura": "NL",
        "ph": "≥3,5",
        "concetracionClMax": "NL",
        "azufreElemental": "ND",
        "tratamientoTermico": "Recocido + endurecimiento por envejecido a 620ºC",
        "dureza": "31",
        "comentarios": "Cualquier combinación ",
        "origen": "NORMATIVA",
        "idEnsayo": "",
        "susceptibilidadSsc": null,
        "tipoResultado": "A",
        "ensayos": null,
        "h2S": "0,103"
    },
    {
        "idMaterial": "AISI 415 (12Cr5NiMo)_S41500",
        "tipoMaterial": "AISI 415 (12Cr5NiMo)",
        "uns": "S41500",
        "temperatura": "NL",
        "ph": "≥3,5",
        "concetracionClMax": "NL",
        "azufreElemental": "ND",
        "tratamientoTermico": "Austenitizado + templado + doble revenido",
        "dureza": "23",
        "comentarios": "Cualquier combinación de T y [Cl] en medios de producción es aceptable",
        "origen": "NORMATIVA",
        "idEnsayo": "",
        "susceptibilidadSsc": null,
        "tipoResultado": "A",
        "ensayos": null,
        "h2S": "0,103"
    },
    {
        "idMaterial": "13Cr4NiMo_S42400",
        "tipoMaterial": "13Cr4NiMo",
        "uns": "S42400",
        "temperatura": "NL",
        "ph": "≥3,5",
        "concetracionClMax": "NL",
        "azufreElemental": "No",
        "tratamientoTermico": "Austenitizado + templado + doble revenido",
        "dureza": "23",
        "comentarios": "Cualquier combinación de T y [Cl] en medios de producción es aceptable",
        "origen": "NORMATIVA",
        "idEnsayo": "",
        "susceptibilidadSsc": null,
        "tipoResultado": "A",
        "ensayos": null,
        "h2S": "0,103"
    },
    {
        "idMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)_S41425",
        "tipoMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)",
        "uns": "S41425",
        "temperatura": "NL",
        "ph": "≥3,5",
        "concetracionClMax": "NL",
        "azufreElemental": "No",
        "tratamientoTermico": "Austenitizado + templado + revenido",
        "dureza": "28",
        "comentarios": "Cualquier combinación de T y [Cl] en medios de producción es aceptable",
        "origen": "NORMATIVA",
        "idEnsayo": "",
        "susceptibilidadSsc": null,
        "tipoResultado": "A",
        "ensayos": null,
        "h2S": "0,103"
    },
    {
        "idMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)_S41426",
        "tipoMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)",
        "uns": "S41426",
        "temperatura": "NL",
        "ph": "≥3,5",
        "concetracionClMax": "NL",
        "azufreElemental": "No",
        "tratamientoTermico": "Austenitizado + templado + revenido",
        "dureza": "27",
        "comentarios": "Grado máximo 105 Ksi. Cualquier combinación de T y [Cl] en medios de producción es aceptable",
        "origen": "NORMATIVA",
        "idEnsayo": "",
        "susceptibilidadSsc": null,
        "tipoResultado": "A",
        "ensayos": null,
        "h2S": "0,103"
    },
    {
        "idMaterial": "13Cr4Ni_S41429",
        "tipoMaterial": "13Cr4Ni",
        "uns": "S41429",
        "temperatura": "NL",
        "ph": "≥4,5",
        "concetracionClMax": "NL",
        "azufreElemental": "ND",
        "tratamientoTermico": "templado + revenido o normalizado +revenido",
        "dureza": "27",
        "comentarios": "Grado máximo 120 Ksi .Cualquier combinación de T y [Cl] en medios de producción es aceptable",
        "origen": "NORMATIVA",
        "idEnsayo": "",
        "susceptibilidadSsc": null,
        "tipoResultado": "A",
        "ensayos": null,
        "h2S": "0,103"
    }
]
```

Use the **.map** function to fetch the fields.

```
function grabFields(item, index) {
    var idMaterial = item.idMaterial;
    var uns = item.uns;
    return {
       idMaterial: idMaterial,
       uns: uns
    }
}
```

Output the fetched values to screen.

```
console.log(obj.map(grabFields));
```

Comment: this function return [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]. How can stringify obj?console.log(JSON.stringify((obj).map(grabFields)). If I use stringify I can't use map function

Comment: Just try, `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.map(grabFields)));`

Comment: Sorry, I did wrong the question. Let's start again :P. This is my JSON object: var obj = [ { "idMaterial": "Alloy 450 (15Cr6Ni1.5Cu)_S45000", "tipoMaterial": "Alloy 450 (15Cr6Ni1.5Cu)", "uns": "S45000", }, { "idMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)_S41425", "tipoMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)", "uns": "S41425", }, { "idMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)_S41425", "tipoMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)", "uns": "S41425", }, ...etc ];see that element "idMaterial": "13Cr5Ni2Mo (Súper 13 Cr)_S41425" is repeated. That I want is to get a JSON object with repeated elements